# Color profile keeps changing in Win 10 after hardware events

Tags: windows-10, color-profiles

I have a Lenovo E480 Thinkpad laptop with win 10 pro with an Intel UHD 620 graphics card. My laptop always had a yellowish colour cast when I was using either the laptop's own monitor or an external one. Recently I downloaded some updated colour profiles and set them as defaults in the Windows' Colour Management panel (advanced system settings).

The new profiles work great, except when I happen to plug in a USB device or (un)mount a virtual drive or on some other random occassions when Windows will just reset the colour profile back to that yellowish setup and informing me (in the Colour management panel) at times that due to hardware changes the profiles have been reset - though not to the newly-set default settings apparently!

I am at my wits end, since I tried every other solution that I could find on the internet in the last few days, yet none of them do the trick. My drivers are up-to-date, I can't seem to find any relevant settings in the Intel Graphics Control Panel that would address this, I have no "Intel User Interface" process running at startup. Some windows process or another must be responsible for this, but which it is, I haven't got a clue. And I dread going to Microsoft support forums since their personnel always just tells you to update your display driver ...

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Frustratingly, the situation resolved itself without me being able to know what the actual solution itself was (perhaps a firmware update from my Lenovo Vantage application or just a regular Win 10 update).

Comment: Mine also does it whenever a device goes offline/online on the network. I think it started with a Win10 update from April. I followed instructions from several threads (such as https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/8gudps/random_flickering_of_custom_icc_color_profile/ ) but nothing fixed it so far: automatic/manual color management, removing all other profiles, installing newest/oldest drivers, disabling power saving, etc

Comment: Thank your comment. With me nothing helped, but somehow, about, two or three weeks ago, the situation just resolved itself so that the color profiles now stay put when I (un-)plug USB devices. So the situation is solved now, but I can't say what the solution is, since I don't know it - perhaps it was one of the firmware updates for my Lenovo laptop Vantage application or just a normal Windows update. On the on hand, I'm glad that the situation is fixed, but on the other hand, since I don't know what fixed it, this kind of bothers me, since I can't fix it if it happens again ...